# shopware 6.5, how to get details of product when promocode is applied

Tags: symfony, events, shopware

Hello I am trying to capture and store the list of cart items after an order has been made.

I am able to do this by :

```
 $order = $event->getOrder();

 $lineItems = $order->getLineItems();
```

and then I have a for each loop which carries

```
   foreach ($lineItems as $details) {

 $productId = $details->getProductId();

 $criteria = new Criteria();

 $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('id', $productId));

  $product = $this->productRepository->search($criteria, $event->getContext())->first();
```

e.g I get my price like this

```
$priceCollection = $product->getPrice();
```

all this is fine and works until I try to apply  a promo code and I get a

```
Call to a member function getPrice() on null
```

please what is the reason for getPrice now been null?

I need to have these details with or without using the promo code.